# What's the consensus on content edits to very old questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a number of suggested edits in the queue for very old questions (3+ years ago) where the edit does nothing but tweak the question's phrasing, capitalization, or punctuation. While the edits probably *do* improve the question marginally, my inclination is to reject the edit because it doesn't make a substantial improvement and needlessly re-raises a long-settled issue on the homepage.

Is there a community recommendation or consensus on this, though? Should these edits typically be pushed through, since they are in good faith and improve the question in a small way? I don't want to be "that guy" pushing Reject, Reject, Reject.

Answer (score 9):

I too am more likely to reject an edit if it is on a very old post. An edit to a year(s) old post needs to carry more weight to go through most of the time.

To be honest, though, I typically don't accept purely superficial edits on any post which is more than a day old.

Comment: I tend to use that approach too. I know if you are a newish user that getting edits accepted can be a way to grow your rep, but it should still be worthwhile making the changes.

Comment: Its more likely newbies trying to get more points on SE though initial edits.